# How to configure Spring Boot to write MultiPartFile to disk?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipart

The documentation of MultiPartFile says that

> The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk.

I want to be sure that the multipart file is not stored in memory, rather it is stored on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways but this code will surely help you easily.

```
private void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws Exception {
    String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); 
    multipartFile.transferTo(new File(filePath));
}
```

or you can define your own custom path.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that it keeps in the memory the whole file for a moment, then transfers to the disk ?

Comment: The other way around is not possible as file needs to be created first. And that part is in memory in all frameworks.

Comment: But after calling transferTo it's not in memory anymore right ?

Comment: Correct. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Okay, but it would be nice to eliminate this moment of having it in the memory.